# How to update cust_id from Customer table to order table Cust_id field while inserting customer name using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064, eventtrigger

I have two tables 1. **Customer_details** and 2. **Order_details**.

** 1.**Customer_details table** -->fields--> Cust_Id(Primary Key) and Customer_Name, 2.Order_details table --> fields-- Ord_Id(Primary Key), Cust_id, (There is no field for Customer name in Order_details table).  I am trying to insert customer name to **order_details** by CSV file through application code. When insert customer name to **order_details** table it should check the corresponding Customer name- Custid from **Customer_details** table and insert the relevant customer name Custid to **order_details** table. Need to implement this in **Database level** not in application coding level. Searching lot in this and cant figure out. I possible need to implement with **trigger**. Kindly help with the code.

Thanks,
Acube.

Comment: Typically, one's application would know the `Cust_id` when it sends the `INSERT INTO orders ...` statement to the RDBMS...

Comment: while inserting the customer name in order details table the cust_id should be populated from customer details table

Comment: i don't need to do this in application level and i need to implement this in Database level. so i guess trigger will help. since this is the requirement, i need customer name in both tables.

Comment: then should i have to remove the customer name field from order details table

Comment: Yes, exactly correct.

Comment: thanks eggyal, but what i understood the requirement is totally wrong, sorry for that. I have a ordertable there is no customer name  field now(Deleted it), but i am inserting data through csv to db through app. what i need is when inserting the customer name in order table, it should automatically get the relevant cust id from customer table and populate it in the order table. is this possible in DB level using trigger.  Really sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: It's not a task for a trigger.  It's something that should be implemented either within one's application code, or else one can use the `SET` clause of the `LOAD DATA` command to obtain the relevant id via a subquery.  However, you might want to consider the reliability of your CSV data: for example, what happens when two customers share the same name?

Comment: How to do it with SET clause of the LOAD DATA, can you help with the subquery

Comment: `LOAD DATA ... (col1, col2, col3, @username, col5) SET user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = @username)`.